# Vue - Wrong values when using multiple checkboxes and radio in paginated form

Tags: vue.js

I try to make a dynamic form using pagination. On each page there may be a collection of checkboxes or radio buttons. These are the answers options to questions. There may be one or multiple answers for a question, hence the radios and checkboxes. The given answers must be stored as a value to a parameter for each question. Everything seems to work fine as long as I use just radios or just checkboxes. As soon as I mix the two and use the pagination things get messed up. I made a VUE playground to illustrate the problem:

https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Above the inputs you see the result of de checkedNames var. If you move to the third question, you'll see this var also holds the answers to the second question.

I also have an example without the pagination. There everything works as expected:

https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Doe anybody know what's wrong with my script?

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formPosition: 0,
      groups:[{
        title: 'girls',        
        checkedNames: [],
        type: 'checkbox',
        names: ['Mary','Emma','Olivia']
      },
      {
        title: 'boys',
        checkedNames: [],
        type: 'checkbox',
        names: ['Jack','John','Mike']
      },
      {
        title: 'Choose one',
        checkedNames: '',
        type: 'radio',
        names: ['Red','Green','Yellow','Purple']
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextStep(){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.formPosition += 1;
      }, 400);
    },
    prevStep(){

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.formPosition -= 1;
      }, 400);
    }
  }
      
}
</script>

<template>

  <div id="'section' + formPosition">
    
    <h4>
      {{ groups[formPosition].title }}
    </h4>
    <div>Checked names: {{ groups[formPosition].checkedNames }}</div>
    
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(name, idx) in groups[formPosition].names" :key="'answer'+ idx">
        <input :type="groups[formPosition].type" :id="name" :value="name" :name="'question'+ name" v-model="groups[formPosition].checkedNames" />
            <label :for="name">{{ name }}</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button 
              class="btn btn-primary"
              v-if="formPosition !== 0" 
              @click="prevStep">
        &lsaquo; Previous
      </button>
      <button 
              class="btn btn-primary"
              v-if="formPosition !== groups.length"
              @click="nextStep">
        Next &rsaquo;
      </button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with reactivity and the inputs and their bound v-model not updating properly.  Since every page has a unique `formPosition`, adding that as a `key` to the component root div should help Vue's reactivity system understand when to update.  Keeping all your same code, change just the first div:

```html
<div id="'section' + formPosition" :key="formPosition">
```

Comment: That is a very neat solution indeed! Thanks a lot. I changed my script to this.

Answer (score 1):

I realised the radio element is not the same as a checkbox element even though in code it's just the type that changes. And even though the appearance changed, the initiated element's behaviour did probably not change. So I changed this part of my code:

```
<li v-for="(name, idx) in groups[formPosition].names" :key="'answer'+ idx">
        <input :type="groups[formPosition].type" :id="name" :value="name" :name="'question'+ name" v-model="groups[formPosition].checkedNames" />
            <label :for="name">{{ name }}</label>
      </li>
```

to this:

```
<li v-for="(name, idx) in groups[formPosition].names">
        <input v-if="groups[formPosition].type === 'checkbox'" type="checkbox" :id="name" :value="name" v-model="groups[formPosition].checkedNames" />
        <input v-else type="radio" :id="name" :value="name" v-model="groups[formPosition].checkedNames" />
            <label :for="name">{{ name }}</label>
      </li>
```

And now it's working as expected

Comment: A mismatch between the underlying code and the UI is a sign that reactivity has broken in some way.  See my answer for an easier fix